# Smart documentation for LaTeX in IDE

Tags: ide

I'm currently writing my thesis and I realize that it's just no fun doing it with LaTeX. I always have to go online to find out any little thing. It's becoming so time consuming. So my question is: is there an IDE or something that helps you write LaTeX code and view a documentation in the IDE (I mean smart documentation that shows documentation for the currently viewed function).

I used LaTeX for many projects by now and I don't use it so frequently that I memorize everything. I rely on my old projects or example projects which is not very good.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If you're using some IDE that supports language servers you could use the TexLab server. It doesn't show the documentation of everything, but it gives quite reasonable autocompletion suggestions, and for many packages it can display a short explanation.

Comment: Perhaps the [LaTeX2e-help](https://ctan.org/pkg/latex2e-help-texinfo) which can be downloded from CTAN in html-format for offline-usage is of use to you. Besides this, my system, TeXLive 2021, comes along with [Texdoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/latex2e-help-texinfo), a command-line tool for finding and viewing documentation locally installed together with TeXLive. MiKTeX used to have a similar tool. Under Windows I used to use WinEdt. Back then I had a search within the LaTeX2e-help integrated into WinEdt's context menus. I don't know what WinEdt is like nowadays.

Comment: And if you're a user of VIM (that would support the language server protocol via plugins) you could as well install the VimTeX plugin that rebinds the `K` binding to use texdoc instead of the programmers man pages (if you're familiar with VIM you understood what I said, if not best not try VIM for an immediate productivity boost, which seems like what you're after).

Comment: LaTeX is a moving carpet and a contextual IDE is desirable and sounds possible. What would it entail?
Something like how SyncTex does it with "Jump to Source" and "Jump to PDF", only more so, and nested (possibly with branchings),  since function `f` and variable `v` are defined (or re-defined from their kernal definitions, if any) in package `p` and then package `p2` redefines `f`... And multi-pass function-generation functions... So, perhaps just for the (common) kernel commands and just the syntax(es), like, "Does `\makeX` take `[]{}` or `{}{}` when in unstarred 2-parm mode?", and so on.

Comment: Definitions confined to (dynamic) local groupings could be tricky to contextualize ... It's as if the first design decision for a smartdocs build is whether expansionability is part of the picture (whether the pop-up help would need a TeX run (or two) to resolve things).

Comment: Translators face a similar issue when they research the meaning of a word. Instead of re-doing the same research again six months later when they come across the word again, they build up a "translation memory" (table) as they go. Perhaps a user "coding memory" equivalent could be implemented. (It could even have attribution of code source, eg @egreg or @davidcarlisle.)

Comment: In your circumstances, a good alternative to edit plain LaTeX is LyX, that is not a WYSIWYG word processor, but rarely you will need to type any raw LaTeX command, while  you can learn of what LyX produce in LaTeX for you. Another alternative is markdown,  that can be exported also cleanly to LaTeX with pandoc.  I recommend Rmarkdown using Rstudio, because there is a visual mode that is similar to use LyX, and it  can include (as well as in LyX) raw latex when you need something special, and export it to PDF via LaTeX without pain.